# Save multiple sheets to .pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I have a reporting spreadsheet that grabs some data from a database and forms three sheets of summary report information. I want to run the spreadsheet automatically from the command line, and have it automatically save all three reporting sheets as a PDF file(s).

At first I thought I could have a VBA macro on the sheet do this by a series of "print as PDF", but that requires an intermediary interactive dialog box to specify the output file name. Then I find that I can just save as pdf, and the macro can set the output file name.
However this creates three separate files, and I have to then later put them together externally to merge them.

(It is odd that save as pdf only saves one sheet, where other save modes seem to save the entire workbook.)

Yes, there are tools for merging the three files later, but I want to know if there is some easy way to get Excel to save multiple sheets together as one pdf file.

I print now by a series of things like:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, ...
```

Could I do instead a single statement something like (pseudo-code):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1,2,3,4).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, ...
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Start by selecting the sheets you want to combine:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: @Tim `+1` this a useful piece :)

Comment: The ability to select an array of sheets worked out wonderfully.  Thank you.

Comment: If you hide workbook with `book.Windows(1).Visible = False` `Sheets(..).Select()` fails. (python3.4, mso2013)

Comment: Is it possible to do this across multiple workbooks?

Comment: Save sheets from different workbooks into the same PDF?  I don't think so.

Comment: If you're worried about users renaming a sheet, you can use the Name method of the sheet instead, like `Thisworkbook.Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name)).Select` so that no matter what a user renames a sheet to the macro will still function. To break that, you have to edit the sheet properties in VBA.

Comment: @AustinWismer only workaround I know of is to use [the `Worksheet.Copy` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) to put them all in a temporary workbook. The upside is then you don't have to use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array()).Select`

Comment: I'm finding that the function just tries (and fails) to export the whole workbook (guessing from the file size of the temporary file) irrespective of the sheet selection.  New version of Excel/ VBA perhaps?

Comment: Well what version are you using?

Comment: Question: Does this require a `namespace`, or just allows you to do it without using the proper `namespace`?(I can't find a `namespace` for this)

Comment: I know this isn't in C#, but this doesn't really make sense to me :D(But that's just me...)

Comment: IMPORTANT: Be sure to use ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat ... NOT ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat ... or all sheets will be exported, not jsut the selected sheets. It's a bit counterintuitive (or was for me).

Answer (score 10):

Similar to Tim's answer - but with a check for 2007 (where the PDF export is not installed by default):

```
Public Sub subCreatePDF()

    If Not IsPDFLibraryInstalled Then
        'Better show this as a userform with a proper link:
        MsgBox "Please install the Addin to export to PDF. You can find it at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041". 
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
        ActiveSheet.Name & " für " & Range("SelectedName").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub

Private Function IsPDFLibraryInstalled() As Boolean
'Credits go to Ron DeBruin (http://www.rondebruin.nl/pdf.htm)
    IsPDFLibraryInstalled = _
        (Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & _
        "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" & _
        Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & _
        "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "")
End Function
```

Comment: Will this work with Excel 2003, too? I mean, will IsPDFLibraryInstalled return false?

Comment: The code here for `IsPDFLibraryInstalled()` has a bug in it. There's supposed to be an <> sign before the final `"")` i.e. the line before `End Function` should be `"\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "")`

Comment: I attempted to edit the code to fix the <> bug and also the missing "If" in "End If" but my edit was rejected.

Comment: @AnotherParker thanks for pointing it out. It actually was there in the source but got lost in the conversion to HTML. Fixed now- thanks

Answer (score 6):

I recommend adding the following line after the export to PDF:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

(where eg. `Sheet1` is the single sheet you want to be active afterwards)

Leaving multiple sheets in a selected state may cause problems executing some code. (eg. unprotect doesn't function properly when multiple sheets are actively selected.)