# Save A Worksheet as A PDF

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am having an issue with saving multiple worksheets as a pdf. I have looked on this website (and others) and found similar code to what I have been using. However, the code that I have modified to more closely resemble [Save multiple sheets to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/excel-save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf) and http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=160 combined.

However, I am running into an error in my last line "424: Object Required". If you could steer me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub SaveAs()

Dim Fname As String
Dim Fpath As String

    Fname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FT5").Text 'The Cell I want to use as my file name
    Fpath = "C:" 'my location

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")).Select 'My selected tabs

    ActiveSheets.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=Fpath & "\" & Fname & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True 'My issue is with this line....
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such object as `ActiveSheets`, therefore your last line does cause an error.

Replace `ActiveSheets` either with `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` if you want to simply print what the user currently has selected or with `Sheets("Sheet 1", "Sheet 3", "Sheet ...")` if you want to selected the sheets with the code.

Comment: I selected yours as the correct answer; however, simply removing the 's' from the end of ActiveSheets was all that I needed to do. Thank you for helping me out Peter!

Comment: Good to know!
Actually, looking at your code again, I'd recommend to simply merge the two last lines to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")).ExportAsFixedFormat(...`

Comment: Thanks, for letting me know I can do that! I think I am going to leave it the way it is though. I want to be able to easily edit my array!

Comment: You still can edit your array - you just remove the intermediate step of actually selecting the worksheets! It's the same principle as to not use `Range.Select`, `Selection.DoSomething` - but rather `Range.DoSomething`. See here for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select