# How to print selected sheets only in excel to PDF using ExportAsFixedFormat in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have multiple sheets in workbook and selected few using

```
 String[] sheetsToBeSelected = { "month", "day" };

 ((Sheets)ws.get_Item(sheetsToBeSelected)).Select();   

 Worksheet sheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet; 

 sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, pdfFileName, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, !isPrintingSilent, Missing.Value);
```

Now I want to print only selectedsheets into PDF not the complete workbook using ExportAsFixedFormat. How I can do that?

I have found the solution and workaround is updated in the code above. Hope it will help others.

Comment: VBA, but you should be able to adapt to C#...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/excel-save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf/14407986#14407986

Comment: I used the code below and it worked                                 Worksheet sheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                        sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, pdfFileName, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, !isPrintingSilent, Missing.Value);

Comment: Hi me how, That thread is about exporting different sheets to different pdf and my question is about exporting to same pdf.

Comment: It is a bit misleading to have a working solution in your question. Better to post your own answer I think.