# Print Multiple Excel sheets in a specific order

Tags: vba, excel, export, pdf-generation

I am trying to print/publish multiple sheets from Excel workbook, but in a specific order. I use the same code used here but it is not printing in the order I inputted into my array and alternatively is printing from leftmost sheet to the rightmost sheet.

[Save multiple sheets to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf/29053520#29053520)

I would like to print the sheets in a specific order. I selected the order that I wanted to print, however, it printed from left most sheet and going to right in the way they were in the workbook. How can I make them print in the order that I inputted in the array.

I selected

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("GIT 100", "GIT 399", "CheckList GIT 400", "TCCC", "4.1")).Select
```

But I got "4.1","CheckList GIT 400","GIT 399","TCCC","GIT 100" as the published document.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just loop:**

```
Sub Kakeda()
    ary = Array("GIT 100", "GIT 399", "CheckList GIT 400", "TCCC", "4.1")
    For Each a In ary
        Sheets(a).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
    Next a
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will save the **.pdf** files separately:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kakeda()
    Dim ary
    Dim a As Variant, fp As String
    ary = Array("GIT 100", "GIT 399", "CheckList GIT 400", "TCCC", "4.1")
    fp = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    For Each a In ary
        Sheets(a).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp & "\" & a & ".pdf"
    Next a
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

This version will create a **single pdf**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kakeda3_TheSequel()
    Dim ary
    Dim a As Variant, fp As String
    ary = Array("GIT 100", "GIT 399", "CheckList GIT 400", "TCCC", "4.1")
    fp = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    For Each a In ary
        Sheets(a).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next a

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work, its saying a type mismatch error

Comment: hey thanks for the code above, but is it possible to publish as one document?

Comment: How can i populate the ary based on the sheets where visible rows are greater than 0. I already have the variables counting the num rows, i just need to populate the ary array to incaputre the sheet names and then i can use your code above.

Comment: I would need the code that examines each sheet and determines the number of visible rows.

Comment: Sheets("Academy").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$U").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks("ABCSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Acount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1


 Sheets("Cambridge").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Workbooks("ABCSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("4.1").Range("$J$5"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Bcount = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

and so on.....

Comment: let me know if u need more info?

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the order of the sheet, make the sheet order as you want to be printed(in sequence), that will work.

Comment: I know but for some other reason i dont want to move the sheets

Comment: then you should create a piece of code to make the sheets in printable order and after the print make the order as it was before...