# Change printing order of Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

By default, Excel prints the worksheets from left to right. Is it possible to change this?

So far, I didn't find any solution. The only thing left is to move the sheets according to the order I want, but I am looking for a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: You can do it using VBA.

Comment: Thanks Elio, do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you know VBA? Take a look at [Print Multiple Excel sheets in a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061072/print-multiple-excel-sheets-in-a-specific-order) it may do what you need.