# Make the new row inside the table

Tags: excel, vba, forms, excel-tables, listobject

```
Sub add_product()
' add_product Macro
' ADD PRODUCT MACRO
' TeachExcel.com
' Takes data from one worksheet and stores in in the next empty row on another worksheet.

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim nextRow As Long

' Make some sheet variables so we can use those instead of hard-coding sheet references in the code.
Set sourceSheet = Sheets("add product")
Set dataSheet = Sheets("products")

' Get the next empty row from the Data sheet.
nextRow = dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

' Input the form values into the Data sheet.
dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = sourceSheet.Range("J5").Value
dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 2).Value = sourceSheet.Range("J7").Value
dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 3).Value = sourceSheet.Range("J9").Value
dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 4).Value = sourceSheet.Range("J11").Value
dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 5).Value = sourceSheet.Range("J13").Value

'Clear Data
sourceSheet.Range("J7").Value = ""
sourceSheet.Range("J9").Value = ""
sourceSheet.Range("J11").Value = ""
sourceSheet.Range("J13").Value = ""
End Sub
```

I want to add the new Row inside the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGRJ2.png)
But as you see in the photo next, the data going outsite the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHu3N.png)

Comment: It seems good this code for you to add a new product at the end of your table. What do you mean "inside the table" ?

Comment: check the [screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHu3N.png)

Comment: @jacouh open the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHu3N.png), the table ends on F7 after I added the last row on F8 using [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGRJ2.png)

Comment: `.End(xlUp).Row` will give the last row of the table even if there are blank rows in the table so offset(1) will be outside the table. What it the table name ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061072/print-multiple-excel-sheets-in-a-specific-order

Comment: **@CDP1802** the table called "table1"

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub add_product()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsData  As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, r As Long
    
    Set wsSource = Sheets("add product")
    Set wsData = Sheets("products")
    
    With wsData.ListObjects("table1")
        .ListRows.Add
        n = .ListRows.Count
                
        ' Input the form values into the Data sheet.
        For i = 1 To 5
            r = 3 + i * 2
            .DataBodyRange.Cells(n, i) = wsSource.Cells(r, "J")
            If r >= 7 Then
               wsSource.Cells(r, "J") = ""
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **@CDP1802** Compile error 
,DataBodyRange.Cells(n, i) = wsSource.Cells(r, "J")

Comment: @YassineHendaoui replace comma with dot at beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the table like so

```
dataSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize dataSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$" & nextRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Write To a New Row of an Excel Table (ListObject)

- Instead of

  ```
  .Range("A1").ListObject
  ```

  - ... if the table is the first or the only table, you will use (better):

    ```
    .ListObjects(1)
    ```
  - ... if you know the name of the table, e.g. `Table1`, you will use (best):

    ```
    .ListObjects("Table1")
    ```

**The Code**

```vb
Sub AddProduct()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Add Product")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("J5,J7,J9,J11,J13")
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(sCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No blank fields allowed.", vbCritical, "Add Product"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Products")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").ListObject.ListRows.Add.Range
    
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        dc = dc + 1
        drg.Cells(dc).Value = sCell.Value
        If dc > 1 Then sCell.ClearContents
    Next sCell

    MsgBox "Product added.", vbInformation, "Add Product"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Solved!
I just changed 
nextRow = dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet. **Rows** .Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
**to**
nextRow = dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet. **ListObjects** .Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

**Thank you all for trying to help me <3**