# Hide all worksheets from excels files except for the first and the second worksheets

Tags: python

I am trying to convert multiple excels to pdfs. I want to get the first and the second worksheet from each file so I think one way is to hide the other worksheets, but I can't find how.

Could you please help me?

Below is the code that converts excels to pdfs.

```
import glob
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
path='/folder_path'
filenames=glob.glob(path +"/*xlsx")

for i in filenames:

  pdf_path = i.replace('xlsx', 'pdf')
  xlApp = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
  books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(i)
  books.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,pdf_path)
  xlApp.Quit()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442476/win32com-saving-exporting-multiple-sheets-as-pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't know the sheetnames. my excels have different sheetnames.