# Printing multiple pages into PDF

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print multiple sheets in PDF Format. Below is the code but it is giving subscript out of range error. Please help

```
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  Worksheets("Report").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = "SPC Report " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".pdf" 'PdfFile & "_" & Worksheets("Report").name & ".pdf"

  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With Worksheets("Report")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtNames).Select
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="SPC Report " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Select
  End With
```

Here is where I declare ShtNames and assign values to it.

```
 Dim ShtNames() As String
  ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count / 2 + 1)
  i = Sheets.Count
  j = 1
  Do While i > Sheets.Count / 2
    ShtNames(j) = Sheets(i).Name
    i = i - 1
    j = j + 1
  Loop
```

Comment: I have edited the question for your reply. Also, the individual array variables in ShtNames is proper such that ShtNames(1), ShtNames(2) are all working properly but it is unable to select the given sheets in a single select statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save multiple sheets to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf)

Comment: it sis not a duplicate but an extension

Answer (score 0):

*Initial problem from OP seems to have been solved. Updated answer to question on how to print sheets in reverse is now included at bottom of answer*
Try setting `j = 0` in the code where your declare `ShtNames`and assign values to it:

I don't see any index specification at the top of your code, so I assume that your arrays are all 0-indexed.

Your `Do While` loop uses the counter `j` to access elements in your `ShtNames`-array, however, it seems to me that you start by accessing the second element of that array (As `ShtNames(0)`is the first element, and `ShtNames(1)` is the second element).

I would suspect that when you then try to assign the last sheet-name to the last index of your `ShtNames`-array, you're index 1 larger than the size you `ReDim`'d it initially.

**To print sheets in reverse order, assign your `ShtNames` in reverse order:**

```
Dim ShtNames() As String
  ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count / 2 + 1)
  i = Sheets.Count
  j = UBound(ShtNames)
  Do While i > Sheets.Count / 2
    ShtNames(j) = Sheets(i).Name
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1
  Loop
```

Comment: Yes. I got it and solved it. But I have one problem. I want to print the pages as per the order in the ShtNames array (i.e) the pdf should be from reverse. The last page should come first and the first page last. Help here is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend assigning your `ShtNames` in reverse order, i.e.:
`j = UBound(ShtNames)`
Then use `j = j-1`in your `Do While` loop. 
Does that solve your problem?