# Type mismatch on excel vba export sheets to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I get a type mismatch error when selecting multiple excel sheets (in an array) for export to a single pdf.

I have multiple sheets in a single excel workbook that I want to export to a single pdf for review and printing. I can export single sheets, each to its own pdf. To handle multiple, varying sheets I have tried to set up a dynamic array with the intent to export the sheets in the array. After the array is defined the sheets(array) are selected and at this point, a type mismatch error occurs.  The code below is adapted from an example I found online.  Additionally, I have tried to view the contents of the array in lieu of select/export to pdf.  Type mismatch occurs with this code as well.  This code is shown below the '@@@@ line below.

I have reviewed 3 or 4 posts on VBA export multiple sheets to pdf and on type mismatch but could not identify any applicable solutions (but could not understand much of what I read either).

And also, "ThisWorkbook.Sheets" code is shown in all the examples I've seen as having a capital 'S' in Sheets.  Every time I try to capitalize the 'S', it is automatically reverted back to a lowercase 's'. ????

Any help is greatly appreciated; thank you.

```
Option Explicit

LastRowRoutes = VV  'LastRowRoutes & VV are Variant
Dim M As Variant
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim cnt As Variant
Dim strFilename As String, strFilepath As String
Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim printSheets As Variant
printSheets = arr
Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
Set wksSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
strFilepath = "E:\"
With wksSheet1
   strFilename = strFilepath & "TripSheets_Print.pdf"
End With
cnt = 0
For M = 22 To LastRowRoutes
    If Worksheets(M).Range("B4").Value <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To cnt)
        arr(cnt) = Worksheets(M).Range("A1:K43")
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Else
    End If
Next
ThisWorkbook.sheets(printSheets).Select  '*Type Mismatch here
wksSheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
'@@@@@@@@ code below to view array contents in lieu of select & export
For M = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'type mismatch here as well
    msg = msg & arr(M) & vbNewLine
Next M
MsgBox "the values of my array are: " & vbNewLine & msg
```

Comment: You're trying to use an array as a single worksheet? Perhaps you mean to do `ThisWorkbook.Worksheeets(printSheets(0))...`?  Also, as far as I can tell, both `arr` and therefore `printSheets` are empty...Add `printSheets = arr` after the `arr` is updated in that `For M` loop.

Comment: `printsheets(?)`

Comment: To fix the lowercase `s` in `sheets` - add a new variable - `Dim Sheets`, and then delete it.

Comment: @BruceWayne each element of `arr` is an array: `arr(cnt) = Worksheets(M).Range("A1:K43")`.

Comment: @BigBen - Yeah, but he declares `printSheets = arr` before `arr` is assigned anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BruceWayne I agree with that problem, it's just that `arr` is problematic too...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to put the 'printSheets = arr' statement after your 'For, Next' loop or it will always be empty.  If you step through the code, does arr(cnt) actually get any values inserted?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried to edit the posting but the editor keeps throwing up error that it's code & to indent 4 spaces - can't figure out how to get around it.  Lower case 's' fixed, thanks.  Moving printSheets=arr after loop did not help.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650.  This works but I have to code in the specific sheets in the array which I can't do in practice.  Question is How do I dynamically list the sheets in the array?  If I can do that I can solve the problem.  Thank you - j22