# VBA PrintOut PrintToFile Not Working (previously working two months ago)

Tags: excel, vba, printing, adobe, postscript

In my excel workbook I created a VBA macro that automatically prints (with no prompt) one of the sheets to a .ps and then calls adobe distiller to convert it to a .pdf. As of 6/23/20 this worked without issue. Today, I'm running into the following error:

"Run-time error '1004': Method 'PrintOut' of object 'Sheets' failed"

And it highlights the following code:

[image]

I'm guessing this has to do with recent updates to office 365/windows 10 over the last 1-2 months. However, it is unclear since my company controls when such updates are applied. I thought I would come here to determine if there are any known causes/workarounds.

As far as I know, the only way to print in VBA without a prompt is to use the printtofile.... let me know otherwise. Thanks in advance for your help, feel free to ask if any additional information could help you respond to this error.

Comment: Pretty sure you can print directly to PDF.  Eg:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf/14407986#14407986

Comment: Awesome! Does the job ^_^ (more straightforward as well). I'll have to ensure there are no major differences between save as vs. print but I expect this will work.

Big thanks Tim.