# Exporting specific sheets to PDF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pdf

I have a table called Overview which has a column that represents sheet names I wish to export as a single PDF.
the msgbox returns printarray as the correct text. if I type the text in manually to the 'Sheets(Array(Printarray)).Select' line it will return a single PDF.

but form then on I am stuck.... please help..

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
Dim FolderPath As String
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("Overview")
DStot = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

For DS = 2 To DStot + 1 Step 1
    If DS = DStot + 1 Then
        Printarray = Printarray & Chr(34) & Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value & Chr(34)
    ElseIf DS = 2 Then
        Printarray = Chr(34) & Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value & Chr(34) & ","
    Else
        Printarray = Printarray & Chr(34) & Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value & Chr(34) & ","
    End If
Next DS

msgbox(Printarray)

    Sheets(Array(Printarray)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Sales", _
        openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
Sheets("config").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your issue is that you are passing a single string `"Sheet2, Sheet3"` into `Array()` instead of the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404650/save-multiple-sheets-to-pdf). Checkout [this](https://www.tachytelic.net/2019/09/vba-add-item-array/) and see if that works. Hope that works!

Comment: I can't get it to work...I'm sure I'm just a rank amateur

Comment: Sub ExportAsPDF()
Set VbaArrayNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Dim FolderPath As String
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("Overview")
DStot = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
For DS = 2 To DStot + 1 Step 1
VbaArrayNames.Add Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value
Next DS
Sheets(VbaArrayNames).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Sales", openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
Sheets("config").Select
End Sub

Comment: Sub ExportAsPDF()
Set VbaArrayNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Dim FolderPath As String
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("Overview")
DStot = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

For DS = 2 To DStot + 1 Step 1
    Sheets(Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value).Select False
Next DS

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Sales", _
        openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
Sheets("config").Select
End Sub

Comment: Sorted with above thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Sub ExportAsPDF()
Set VbaArrayNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
Dim FolderPath As String
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("Overview")
DStot = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

For DS = 2 To DStot + 1 Step 1
Sheets(Sheets("Overview").Range("A" & DS).Value).Select False
Next DS

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & "\Sales", _
    openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
```

Sheets("config").Select
End Sub